# Define polynomials over a finite field

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

I have a very basic question in number theory. How could we define a polynomial over a finite field which has "prime power" elements? As far as I know, if a field has prime power elements, it will include polynomials as field elements. But if we try to define a polynomial over this field, we will get a polynomial for which the coefficients are also polynomials (field elements).

I'm confused. Could someone give me a simple example?

Comment: What is "a prime power element"? And why do you think elements in a field are polynomials??

Comment: prime power element means that the number of elements inside the field is a prime power like 8 (2 to the power of 3)

Comment: Oooh! Well, I couldn't have ever guessed that. Anyway, if you want a standard notation for that you can use $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}=\;$ the field (the unique one up to isomorphism) with $\;p^n\;$ elements, $\;p\;$ a prime.

Comment: A better phrasing is "a prime power ***number of*** elements". The way you've written it sounds like you are asserting that each element of a finite field is a prime power.

Comment: Incidentally, there's nothing wrong with polynomials having coefficients named by polynomials. Or even coefficients that are actually drawn from a polynomial ring. In fact, it is fairly useful to view the bivariate polynomial ring $R[x,y]$ as being the ring of univariate polynomials $S[y]$ over the ring $S$, where $S = R[x]$ is the ring of univariate polynomials over $R$.

Answer (score 3):

It may help to understand that there is more than one way of thinking about a polynomial.  One way that you may be more familiar with is as a function that transforms the elements of a field.  Consider for example the polynomial $p(x) = x^2 + 1$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ (we'll consider prime powers later).  As a function, $p(0) = 1$ and $p(1) = 0$.  We could also consider the polynomial $q(x) = x + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  As a *function*, $q$ corresponds to the same mapping as $p$.  However, as *polynomials*, we cannot say that $p(x) = q(x)$ because they have different coefficients.

In a similar fashion, a polynomial over a field of prime power order is defined by its coefficients.  To see this, it may help to use a different indeterminate to write out the coefficients if you must write them explicitly.  For an arbitrary example, you might write the polynomial where the coefficient of $x^2$ is $y + 2$ and the constant term is $3$ over $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ as $(y + 2) x^2 + 3$.  In this context, this would be a polynomial of a single variable because $y + 2$ is a coefficient and not a second indeterminate.  You cannot "simplify" a polynomial by mixing coefficients with indeterminates.  Conceptually, we could also define the polynomial as the vector $(y + 2, 0, 3)$ to make the distinction even clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you mean by *prime power elements*, but I'm afraid you're confusing *polynomials* and  *polynomial functions*.

For instance, let's consider the prime field $\mathbf F_p=\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$, and the polynomial ring $\mathbf F_p[X]$. In this ring, the non-zero polynomial $X^p-X$ induces the polynomial function
\begin{align}f\colon\mathbf F_p&\longrightarrow
\mathbf F_p\\x&\longmapsto x^p-x,
\end{align}
which is $0$ by *Little Fermat*.

Comment: In short: with polynomials it's all about coefficients, with polynomial functions it's all about values.

Comment: Absolutely. Let me add there's an isomorphism between them in characteristic $0$.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers: I'm not sure either, as  the O.P. question was rather confusing. I answered what seemed most likely to me, waiting for some reaction to adjust what I could explain